# CAN-bus communication in the beaglebone

Tags: c#, beagleboneblack, can-bus

I am working on implementing CAN-bus communication between the ARS308 radar from continental and the beaglebone black. Additionally to this two devices I have connected the MCP2551 to translate the CAN signals to Rx/Tx. 
The issue is that when configuring the communication (once the lib-socket and can-utils package were installed):

1. modprobe can
2. modprobe can-dev
3. modprobe can-raw
4. ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000

Until this point everything seems to work perfectly but when the can communication is started:

5. ifconfig can0 up

The waveform of the signal at the Rx pin in the beaglebone (Rx pin of the MCP2551) changes its waveform, and the low voltage level is above two volts. See pictures below.

http://imageshack.com/a/img910/3126/VufRWU.jpg

http://imageshack.com/a/img903/2530/eusAhX.jpg

Once the communication is started, testing the candump commands show that they don't work. Since, when creating a virtual CAN port these tools (candump/cansend) work, my guess is that is a problem of voltage levels. It can be seen that when the CAN communication is started, the low voltage level is above 2V, and the beaglebone cannot differentiate the levels and it doesn't read anything... 
Anyone has experienced this problem? I have tried and googled a lot, but nothing has worked for me. Any thought that can help?!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the loopback.
Instead of:

```
ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
```

put:

```
ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000 loopback on
```

This will allow the system to candump. However the values of candump will be repeated. For testing of your network, you will need another CAN device.